# Prob 5(d) Sec 5 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Any iff condition for a subset of the Cartesian product to be a Cartesian product of the subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $J$ be any given index set. Let $S$ be a subset of the Cartesian product  $\mathbb{R}^J$. Then what is the necessary and sufficient for $S$ to be a Cartesian product $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ of subsets $X_\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for $\alpha \in J$?

In particular, let $S$ be the following subset of the set $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ of all infinite sequences of real numbers: 
$$S \colon= \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \ \colon \ x_2 = x_3 \ \}.$$
Is this $S$ a (countably infinite) Cartesian product of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

An addendum based on the comments:

My feeling is that for $S$  to be a Cartesian product, $S$ must satisfy the following condition:

Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}, \ (y_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \in S$, and let $\beta \in J$ be any index. Then $S$ also contains  the $J$-tuples $(x^\prime_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}$ and $(y^\prime_\alpha )_{\alpha \in J}$, where 
$$
x^\prime_\alpha \colon= 
\begin{cases} 
x_\alpha \ \mbox{ if } \ \alpha \neq \beta; \\
y_\alpha \ \mbox{ if } \ \alpha = \beta,
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
y^\prime_\alpha \colon= 
\begin{cases} 
y_\alpha \ \mbox{ if } \ \alpha \neq \beta; \\
x_\alpha \ \mbox{ if } \ \alpha = \beta.
\end{cases}
$$
I feel that the above condition is both necessary and sufficient.

But I'm unable to determine if this is indeed the case. Nor am I able to rigorously demonstrate this to be the case.

Comment: What are your thoughts about it? Have you consulted the definition of the Cartesian product?

Comment: You will find it easier to get help on this site if you show us any work you've done on the problem, or least as Carl suggests, your thought on the problem.

Comment: Suppose that $J=\mathbb{N}$ and that $S=\{(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}\,|\,\{\alpha\in J\,|\,x_\alpha \neq 1\}\text{ is finite}\}$. I claim $S$ satisfies your condition. Is it a product?